# Where is the man page for the "rename.ul" command?

Tags: manpage, helpfile

The man page for the command "rename.ul" has disappeared and I would like to install it, read it on-line or whatever, but it would be better to have it installed as it was before, in the good times. It is a useful command and it is not a good idea to have its man page redirected to "rename"'s man page because it is a different command.

Answer (score 3):

## If You Don't Have *Any* `rename.ul` Manual Page

Searching the web-based [Ubuntu Manpage Repository](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) for `rename.ul` reveals that [its manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html) is [in page 1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=rename.ul&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/&ref=&ss=1332j309444j11) of the manual. Therefore, the name of the manpage file is `rename.ul.1.gz`.

Searching the [package contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rename.ul.1.gz&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) for that file reveals the [packages that provide it](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rename.ul.1.gz&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any):

- `manpages-fr-extra`
- `util-linux`

Unless you want the French manpage, `util-linux` is the package you want for `rename.ul` manpage.

- It almost always works to simply [search for the command itself](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rename.ul&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) in package contents, as the package that provides the command is virtually always the package that provides its manpage(s).

If you didn't have `util-linux` installed, you could install it. But this is quite an essential package, and it's unlikely you don't have it. So if you're missing the manpage, perhaps somehow that file was deleted. Then you should *reinstall* `util-linux`:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install util-linux
```

## If You Want `man rename.ul` To Give You the Old Manpage in Ubuntu

None of [these six versions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=rename.ul&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/&ref=&ss=1487j867397j9) of `rename.ul`'s manpage in Ubuntu show a *separate* manpage for `rename.ul`, different from `rename`. Please note that the `ul` in `rename.ul` stands for `util-linux`. The `rename` command in Ubuntu is provided by `util-linux`, so any other manpage for it would probably not correctly document the command.

There *are* [other manual pages called `rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=rename&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html&ref=manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=rename.ul&op=&cx=003883529982892832976%253A5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID%253A9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%252F&ref=&ss=1487j867397j9&ss=299j25499j6). But they are for the system and library calls, *not* for the `rename` command.

**With that said, if you find a `rename` manpage online, you can download it and view it like an installed manpage with `man -C ./filename`**. Please note that the `./` is necessary when specifying a manpage located in the current directory with a relative path (just like it's necessary to run a script in the current directory).